# Updating jquery version in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm running rails3 and was going to play around with jquery mobile, but it requires jQuery 1.5, and my install is currently using 1.4

When I run

```
rails g jquery:install
```

I get a jQuery UJS error, but it might not matter because it says 'downloading jQuery 1.4.4', which is the same version I already have.

When I request jQuery v 1.6.1 from with the javascript_include_tag, rails says that the version of jQuery isn't compatible with rails.

Should I just turn off the error?? If so, how?
Or should I somehow update something else in rails?

How can I update the version of jQuery?

Comment: Rails 3, should I just update to 3.1?